# How to swipe XCUIElementTypePickerWheel and select an element?

Tags: iphone, selenium-webdriver, swipe, appium-ios

How can i Select an element/item by rotating the picking wheel in iPhone 7 app through code using Appium 1.6.3?

```
                              <XCUIElementTypePicker name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/0/1/0/0/1/1" x="0" y="520" width="414" height="216">
                                <XCUIElementTypePickerWheel name="" label="" value="default, 3 of 6" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/0/1/0/0/1/1/0" x="0" y="482" width="414" height="292">
                                    <XCUIElementTypeOther name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="false" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/0/1/0/0/1/1/0/0" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0">
                                    </XCUIElementTypeOther>
                                    <XCUIElementTypeOther name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="false" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/0/1/0/0/1/1/0/1" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0">
                                    </XCUIElementTypeOther>
                                    <XCUIElementTypeOther name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="false" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/0/1/0/0/1/1/0/2" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0">
                                    </XCUIElementTypeOther>
                                    <XCUIElementTypeOther name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="false" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/0/1/0/0/1/1/0/3" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0">
                                    </XCUIElementTypeOther>
                                    <XCUIElementTypeOther name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="false" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/0/1/0/0/1/1/0/4" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0">
                                    </XCUIElementTypeOther>
                                    <XCUIElementTypeOther name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="false" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/0/1/0/0/1/1/0/5" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0">
                                    </XCUIElementTypeOther>
                                </XCUIElementTypePickerWheel 
                             <XCUIElementTypePicker>
```

I tried with this `driver.swipe(xstart,ystart,xend,yend,10);`  But not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.swipe(xstart,ystart,xend,yend,10);
```

The end point I used in Appium1.6.5 moved to `(xstart+xend,ystart+yend)` actually.

You should try it.

Comment: Swipe method has deprecated and cannot be used.